# WPF RichTextBox supporting smileys and bootstrap glyphicons

Tags: c#, wpf, twitter-bootstrap

I am creating control which can accepts smileys/emotions and bootstrap glyphicons.

I am using this article for my reference-
http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/599014/WPF-RichTextBox-supporting-smileys

So far my solution is working as mentioned in above article. Now the next task is to include support bootstrap glyphicons.

Is there a way to handle bootstrap glyphicons in WPF rich textbox or should I just move away from rich text box and look for some other options?

Any inputs are welcomed.

Thanks in advance.